# python social auth: get email from Google OAuth2

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I configured the login with google in a Django project. I'm able to get the name and last name but the user is saved with an empty email. I configured the scope in this way:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'profile',
    'email'
]
```

But the email continues saving as "". Am I writing the scopes in bad way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
```

it will collect user email and profile name store it into `USER` model.

Comment: where to add this?